# jest - how to check if a word is a english word

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs

I am using Jest to test for a function, which generate a english word.

I tried below but not working. Just want to check if the word is combined by english characters

```
  it("generate a english word", () => {
    const word = "APPLE";
    expect(word).toMatch('/^[A-Za-z]*$/');
  });
```

What's wrong with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This test

```
expect(word).toMatch('/^[A-Za-z]*$/');
```

tries to match the **string** `'/^[A-Za-z]*$/'`.
You want to pass it as a regular expression instead

```
expect(word).toMatch(/^[A-Za-z]*$/);
```

The lack of quotation marks in the second case makes all the difference.

Here is the link to the documentation https://jestjs.io/docs/expect#tomatchregexp--string